# curl always returns two headers

Tags: security, curl, terminal

I have tried using curl both from Windows and Mac OS X and they always produce the same result. I am initiating a request against a realm and I am using the `--digest` flag to authenticate:

`curl <options> --digest --user admin <endpoint> -v -v --raw`

All of my calls result in two headers:

```
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7f908c80ba00
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7f908c80ba00) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to localhost port 8002 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8002 (#0)
* Server auth using Digest with user 'admin'
> PUT /endpoint HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: localhost:8002
> Accept: */*
> Content-type: application/xml
> Content-Length: 0
> 
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="public", qop="auth", nonce="e54fba22d0eca67e26155cf243dcf4ca", opaque="370985129eb9e9d5"
< Content-type: application/xml
* Server <X> is not blacklisted
< Server: <X>
< Content-Length: 173
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=5
< 
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://localhost:8002/endpoint'
* Found bundle for host localhost: 0x7f908b6095c0
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host localhost
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8002 (#0)
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7f908c80ba00
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7f908c80ba00) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* Server auth using Digest with user 'admin'
> PUT /endpoint HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Digest username="admin", realm="public", nonce="e54fba22d0eca67e26155cf243dcf4ca", uri="/endpoint", cnonce="ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDEzOTc5NzM3MzY=", nc=00000001, qop=auth, response="47da275c9b69e8541ed335a040d4d10d", opaque="370985129eb9e9d5"
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: localhost:8002
> Accept: */*
> Content-type: application/xml
> Content-Length: 118
> 
* upload completely sent off: 118 out of 118 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
* Server <X> is not blacklisted
< Server: <X>
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=5
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Why do I always get the 401 header? I'd expect to see that with the `--anyauth` flag but not with the `--digest`.

Comment: Your log says `PUT /endpoint` you are doing PUT request. But your content length is zero `Content-Length: 0`. So please edit and upload your exact curl command in the question.

Comment: With or without the content it's the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get to see all headers curl gets.

With --digest curl MUST get a 401 first to get the nonce etc to be able to do the second request that would get the real data.

With --anyauth, curl doesn't even assume there is an authentication present so it'll "probe" the page by doing a plain request first (much like a browser would do) and then based on the 401 response it'll act. So yes, if you do --anyauth and if then curl deems digest to be the most suitable authentication method to use out of the ones the server says it supports for the resource, then there will be 3 requests issued to the server.

Answer (score 1):

To properly authenticate at a HTTP server that is using http authorization, it need to make atleast 1 request to the server to get the type of authorization that is used. This is the first request that it makes. The server responds back to this request with the used encoding method for seding the passwords to the server, in this case it is:

```
< WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="public", qop="auth", nonce="e54fba22d0eca67e26155cf243dcf4ca", opaque="370985129eb9e9d5"
```

These values the client recieved from the server are used to generate hashes with the password, so sniffers cannot se the password without brute forcing the passwords back. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) has an exact description how the nonce is hashed with the password to generate a key. These hashes are used to send back another HTTP request to the server, as seen by the following output

> Authorization: Digest username="admin", realm="public", nonce="e54fba22d0eca67e26155cf243dcf4ca", uri="/endpoint", cnonce="ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDEzOTc5NzM3MzY=", nc=00000001, qop=auth, response="47da275c9b69e8541ed335a040d4d10d", opaque="370985129eb9e9d5"

This is the second request curl is making, and uploads the actual data you are sending (0 bytes to /endpoint)

Answer (score 0):

Curl makes two requests, because it needs the server provided nonce (random, single-use value) from the 401 response, so it can create a proper WWW-Authenticate header.

Comment: Thanks. One more question. How does --anyauth and --digest changes the nonce? If I have --anyauth would there be 3 trips to the server?